# What is the Need for AI Developers since we have AI APIs Now?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, open-ai, software-development, ai-development

I am new to AI and passionate about it. I have a fair knowledge of deep learning and I am into computer vision. I am eyeing NLP as well.

I just want to know the need for an AI developer in computer vision, say, since we already have computer vision APIs that a software developer can integrate his newly developed app on to recognize objects.

Thanks

Comment: Where will new research and implementations that lead to APIs (possibly) come from with no AI developers?

Comment: That is true. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though APIs exist, it does not mean that the work is done.

APIs are usually created to allow developers to more easily integrate what exists, but not to innovate the thing that the API wraps around. Even though there are computer vision models that are fairly good, *they can be better*. To improve any kind of model, be it computer vision, GPT model, or any kind of industry application, we will need AI Developers/Data Scientists/All other titles to bring us new, better/more intelligent models.

As long as society wants more intelligent machines, industry/academia will need AI developers.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks.

Comment: If the answer sufficiently answers your question, please give it the green checkmark. That way, future stack exchange visitors can better find what they are looking for.